# How to check if parts of a string match to a column data in sql table

Tags: sql, .net, contains, sql-like

I want to write a query which checks the input provided by the user with the column data of my table. i tried using LIKE and CONTAINS but it didnt work for me. eg my table data contains "Bar B Q Tonight" and if user enters "BBQ Tonight", how to deal with it? I have enabled full text-indexing for my table too. I am working on sql server 2005 in visual studio. can anybody guide me?

Answer (score 1):

One approach to deal with is to create separate column on your table which will contain **popular search tags or keywords**, based on that you can show the results to the user.

Comment: i cant do this, as i dnt know what user will search. i need a query to check if substring exists in table data or not

Comment: This is a great idea. I just wanted to know if it is better to keep the tags comma separated or store them in a separate table with one-to-many relationship between the current table and tags table.

Comment: I think comma separated tags will be fine.

Comment: (It depends on your need) You can have comma separated. Also, if the tags are generic & can apply on multiple columns you can create separate Tags table.

Comment: there will be similar acronyms right ? what if BBQ means Be Back Quick?  my answer suggest let the user pick the relevance and to facilitate it store multiple acronyms with multiple definitions if exists.

Answer (score 0):

Synonyms and acronyms are a challenge for information retrieval systems (IR).
Perhaps implement a tiny **Acronym Expansion System**. Acronyms and expanded terms.

When a user enters such words you need to provide a few suggestions or expanded terms. Like in Google do suggestions or you can show couple of similar terms in return for the query and let the user decide which is relevant.

you need minimum three table as I envisage it but depends on context.

1. one table contains stop words so you parse each word in the
   entered phrase and remove all stop words.
2. then search individual    term in acronyms table and if an
   acronym has more than one    definitions you can substitute acronym
   for each definition and pass    it back to user asking which is
   relevant. if this is web environment    it means list of hyperlinks.